# Three js render a static scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

From the tutorial on setting up a basic scene [here](http://threejs.org/docs/#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene) the standard way to call the renderer is something like:

```
function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
render();
```

However I am generating a static image so creating frames seems like overkill. Is there any way to render the scene once and then have the rendered image persist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I needed to do was delay the call to

```
this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
```

until after all calculations in the scene were finished. Calling it immediately after initialising the renderer was resulting in drawing a white screen as nothing else had been calculated yet.

As a stopgap measure I've put it in a window.setTimeout functions, but I guess the proper way to do it is to put it in a callback function when all the other calculations are finished.

Comment: or you could put your call into the window.onload function

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - the issue was that setting up my scene (adding all the meshes) was taking 10 seconds or so on my mobile, so calling render immediately (even in window.onload) was drawing a blank scene. I fixed it my refactoring the code, using BufferGeometries and instanced meshes which reduced my draw calls from ~5000 to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `render()` just call `renderer.render( scene, camera );`